# Is it possible to serialise/deserialise a String in an on chain data account?

Tags: data

I was hoping to have an on-chain data account that stored a string that I could update dynamically from off-chain.  From what I understand though a string is a growable, heap-allocated data structure,  so is it actually possible to do this?  I'm not sure I understand how the on-chain program should know the size of the string to be able to deserialise it (or to be able to create the data account in the first place)

i.e. if i have a struct:

```
#[derive(BorshSerialize, BorshDeserialize, Debug, Clone, PartialEq)]
pub struct IDMap {
    pub id : String
}
```

and get the size of this for creating the account:

```
pub fn get_id_map_size() -> usize {
    let encoded = IDMap {id: "inital_value".to_string()}
        .try_to_vec().unwrap();

    encoded.len()
}
```

will this actually yield anything sensible?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is possible to have an updatable string stored on an account. There are two ways:

- You set a max size for the string during account creation and use strings within the size limit. E.g for string with max size of 50 bytes: ([space reference](https://www.anchor-lang.com/docs/space))

[image: small code example to store string of size upto 50 bytes]

- Using realloc ([check here](https://dev.to/jacobcreech/how-to-change-account-size-on-solana-55b4)). Basically resize the account + pay rent if necessary. But it has it's limitations, max size change per call is 10KB and it can only be done on program owned accounts.